# "getNativeWindowHandle+0x54" on Gluon JavaFX 16 EA 4 via DRM

Tags: javafx, raspberry-pi, gluon, raspberry-pi4, egl

I was following the steps given at [Gluon Documentation](https://docs.gluonhq.com/index.html#_javafx_on_embedded) to run JavaFX on Raspberry Pi 4 via DRM. I downloaded the JavaFX EA 16 builds from [here](https://gluonhq.com/products/javafx/#ea).

`javafx.properties` file :

```
javafx.version=16-internal
javafx.runtime.version=16-internal+28-2020-11-10-180413
javafx.runtime.build=28
```

After cloning the samples repository containing hellofx, I compiled it via javac (according to the steps) and then ran this command to run it using DRM:

```
sudo -E java -Dmonocle.platform=EGL -Djava.library.path=/opt/arm32hfb-sdk/lib -Dmonocle.egl.lib=/opt/arm32fb-sdk/lib/libgluon_drm.so --module-path /opt/arm32fb-sdk/lib --add-modules javafx.controls -cp dist/. hellofx.HelloFX
```

However, this caused the following error :

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x9c3314dc, pid=734, tid=746

#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (11.0.9+11) (build 11.0.9+11-post-Raspbian-1deb10u1)
# Java VM: OpenJDK Server VM (11.0.9+11-post-Raspbian-1deb10u1, mixed mode, serial gc, linux-)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libgluon_drm.so+0x14dc]  getNativeWindowHandle+0x54
#
# No core dump will be written. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/pi/samples/CommandLine/Modular/CLI/hellofx/hs_err_pid734.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   Unknown
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
Aborted
```

It seems that while loading `libgluon_drm.so` in `JavaFXSDK/lib/` fails at getNativeWindowHandle

What's weird is that after I ran `sudo apt install libegl* mesa* libgl*`, it actually succeeded but was asking me to set variable `ENABLE_GLUON_COMMERCIAL_EXTENSIONS` as true, which I had already done.

However, after rebooting, it started showing the same error.

I am using a Raspberry Pi 4 Model B with 2GB RAM. It is running on Raspberry Pi OS 32-Bit with desktop.

I had performed all of this on a clean installation.

Comment: First time you run it, it seems `/dev/card1` is not ready, but it works from the second time on (this will be fixed in an incoming new release). About the flag, you have to add it to your `.bashrc`, so it gets loaded every time you boot.

Comment: @JoséPereda how do i get `/dev/card1` ready? i am sorry if i sound dumb but I have absolutely no knowledge of this..

Comment: @JoséPereda thing is it doesnt really work even in the second time. when i run it again it fails again. that was the only time when it worked.

Comment: The crash happens when the library tries to open `/dev/dri/card1`. If you do `ls -l /dev/dri/` what do you get? Do you see that `card1` listed?

Comment: @JoséPereda Yes i see `card1` listed, along with `card0` and `renderD128`

Comment: @JoséPereda it turns out that /dev/dri/card0 is the one which works in my case. I used `-Degl.displayid=/dev/dri/card0` as mentioned by Johan Vos. It seems that the card0 and card1 is interchanged in my case. According to 6by9, A Raspberry Pi Engineer, "Pi0-3 you only have the vc4 driver, therefore render is via /dev/dri/card0. Pi4 has both vc4 for render, and v3d for 3D. You can probe the devices for their capabilities - only one should acknowledge that it has DRIVER_RENDER or DRIVER_MODESET capabilities."

Comment: Great that it works for you. Probably you can post it as an answer?

Comment: Can you also include in your answer the JavaFX version you are using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Pi4 has both vc4 for render, and v3d for 3D. You can probe the devices for their capabilities - only one should acknowledge that it has DRIVER_RENDER or DRIVER_MODESET capabilities.

[Pi4 DRM questions](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=247540)

The card which JavaFX selects by default is `/dev/dri/card1`. In my case, `/dev/dri/card0` was the one to be used for render, and not `card1`. I solved the issue by using the following runtime argument :

`-Degl.displayid=/dev/dri/card0`

The JavaFX Version I used was `16-ea+5`.