# Gluon Native DRM javaFX error, Unable to start up DRM based JavaFX Native app

Tags: gluon

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65070705/getnativewindowhandle0x54-on-gluon-javafx-16-ea-4-via-drm), which is really close, but not my problem. I too have followed the same instructions, from a fresh install.

Following the [instructions here](https://docs.gluonhq.com/index.html#_setting_up_the_raspberry_pi_4), I have set up 512MB of GPU ram, and am connected via ssh. There is no desktop running, it's entirely booted to CLI. Perhaps there's some undocumented steps by running the raspberry pi os **lite** image?

Instead of library failures, I get:

```
pi@deskscreen4:~/samples/CommandLine/Modular/CLI/hellofx $ sudo -E java -Dmonocle.platform=EGL -Djava.library.path=/opt/arm32hfb-sdk/lib -Dmonocle.egl.lib=/opt/arm32fb-sdk/lib/libgluon_drm.so --module-path /opt/arm32fb-sdk/lib --add-modules javafx.controls -cp dist/. hellofx.HelloFX
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unable to open DISPLAY
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$new$6(GtkApplication.java:173)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.<init>(GtkApplication.java:171)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkPlatformFactory.createApplication(GtkPlatformFactory.java:41)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.Application.run(Application.java:144)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.startup(QuantumToolkit.java:258)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:269)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:158)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:658)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:409)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
    ... 5 more
```

I do not have the `DISPLAY` environment variable set, I have exported the GLUON commercial env var:

```
pi@deskscreen4:~/samples/CommandLine/Modular/CLI/hellofx $ env  | grep GLUON
ENABLE_GLUON_COMMERCIAL_EXTENSIONS=true
pi@deskscreen4:~/samples/CommandLine/Modular/CLI/hellofx $ env  | grep DISPLAY
pi@deskscreen4:~/samples/CommandLine/Modular/CLI/hellofx $
```

When I did this in the past on java8, I did not have any X-Windows environment installed, and I used a setting like so:

```
 -Dembedded=monocle \
 -Dglass.platform=Monocle \
 -Dprism.verbose=true \
```

EDIT: I have found [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65389228/openjfx-16ea-on-pi-3-throws-unsatisfiedlinkerror-for-libprism-es2-monocle-so-li) that are similar, but not the same. If I specify those options, I get a different error, about how it's unable to load the EGL platform:

```
pi@deskscreen4:~/samples/CommandLine/Modular/CLI/hellofx $ sudo -E java -Dmonocle.platform=EGL -Djava.library.path=/opt/arm32hfb-sdk/lib -Dmonocle.egl.lib=/opt/arm32fb-sdk/lib/libgluon_drm.so --module-path /opt/arm32fb-sdk/lib -Dmonocle.glass.platform=Monocle -Dmonocle.platform=EGL -Djavafx.platform=monocle -Dprism.verbose=true -Djavafx.verbose=true --add-modules javafx.controls -cp dist/. hellofx.HelloFXJavaFX launchApplication method: launchMode=LM_CLASS
Prism pipeline init order: es2 sw
Using Double Precision Marlin Rasterizer
Using dirty region optimizations
Using system sized mask for primitives
Not forcing power of 2 sizes for textures
Using hardware CLAMP_TO_ZERO mode
Opting in for HiDPI pixel scaling
Prism pipeline name = com.sun.prism.es2.ES2Pipeline
Loading ES2 native library ... prism_es2_monocle
System.loadLibrary(prism_es2_monocle) succeeded
    succeeded.
GLFactory using com.sun.prism.es2.MonocleGLFactory
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.glass.ui.monocle.EGLPlatformFactory
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.monocle.NativePlatformFactory.getNativePlatform(NativePlatformFactory.java:103)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.prism.es2.MonocleGLFactory.initialize(MonocleGLFactory.java:107)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.prism.es2.ES2Pipeline.<clinit>(ES2Pipeline.java:81)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:315)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.prism.GraphicsPipeline.createPipeline(GraphicsPipeline.java:218)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.init(QuantumRenderer.java:91)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:124)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
GraphicsPipeline.createPipeline failed for com.sun.prism.es2.ES2Pipeline
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:315)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.prism.GraphicsPipeline.createPipeline(GraphicsPipeline.java:218)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.init(QuantumRenderer.java:91)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:124)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot load a native platform from: 'EGL'
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.monocle.NativePlatformFactory.getNativePlatform(NativePlatformFactory.java:126)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.prism.es2.MonocleGLFactory.initialize(MonocleGLFactory.java:107)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.prism.es2.ES2Pipeline.<clinit>(ES2Pipeline.java:81)
    ... 6 more
*** Fallback to Prism SW pipeline
Prism pipeline name = com.sun.prism.sw.SWPipeline
System.loadLibrary(prism_sw) succeeded
(X) Got class = class com.sun.prism.sw.SWPipeline
Initialized prism pipeline: com.sun.prism.sw.SWPipeline
JavaFX: using com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.glass.ui.monocle.EGLPlatformFactory
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.monocle.NativePlatformFactory.getNativePlatform(NativePlatformFactory.java:103)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.monocle.MonocleApplication.<init>(MonocleApplication.java:49)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.monocle.MonoclePlatformFactory.createApplication(MonoclePlatformFactory.java:42)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.Application.run(Application.java:144)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.startup(QuantumToolkit.java:258)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:269)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:158)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:658)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:409)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot load a native platform from: 'EGL'
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.monocle.NativePlatformFactory.getNativePlatform(NativePlatformFactory.java:126)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.monocle.MonocleApplication.<init>(MonocleApplication.java:49)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.monocle.MonoclePlatformFactory.createApplication(MonoclePlatformFactory.java:42)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.Application.run(Application.java:144)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.startup(QuantumToolkit.java:258)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:269)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:158)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:658)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:409)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
    ... 5 more
```

What did I do wrong? Why does it insist upon trying to load GTK as if a desktop environment is there?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I figured it out.

I was using the Bellsoft liberica JDK. That apparently doesn't have the right things, or has conflicty things.

I solved my problem by switching to an adoptopenjdk java11 build. Things fired right up perfectly with some library errors. It fell back to the software pipeline, but that's a known fix:

```
WARNING: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /opt/arm32fb-sdk/lib/libprism_es2_monocle.so: libGLESv2.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

An `apt install libgles2 libgles2-mesa` later, and I [have problems that other people have seen and solved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65070705/getnativewindowhandle0x54-on-gluon-javafx-16-ea-4-via-drm/65122789#65122789)